# make: pwd: Command not found

Tags: cygwin, mingw

I am new to using make files.  I have cygwin and MinGW.  I'm still looking into their differences.

Anyway, I have a makefile that is used to create a project for an FPGA, which I have never done before.  I have included C:\cygwin\bin and C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin in my PATH, but I always get this error.

```
make: pwd: Command not found
```

I typed pwd into the cmd prompt and get a correct response.  Any pointers?  Am I missing something?  Not sure what else I can try.  Most forums I have found pertaining to this error never have a resolution.

Let me know what information you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

`pwd` is commonly both a shell built-in command and a standalone executable, provided by GNU coreutils (which Cygwin installs by default).

If you're invoking `make` from the Cygwin environment (say, typing `make` at a bash shell prompt), then `C:\cygwin\bin` is the wrong way to specify the directory. That's the path as seen from Windows. From within Cygwin, it's `/bin` -- and it should be in your default `$PATH`. The Cygwin equivalent of `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` would be `/cygdrive/c/mingw/msys/1.0/bin`

If you're doing this directly from Windows rather than in the Cygwin subsystem, then `C:\cygwin\bin` is the path to the Cygwin bin directory -- but running `C:\cygwin\bin\pwd` is going to give you a Cygwin-specific directory name that's not going to be meaningful to Windows.

Comment: So what is the solution exactly if someone wants to use cygwin's make with Window's cmd?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue in my mingw environment. It turned out in my case to be a missing 'pwd'executable in the msys/bin directory. Once the copying was done properly, everything fell into place. Hope this helps